# Repostion Ext.MessageBox.alert() without changing the current code

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, extjs, position

I want to get all Ext.MessageBox.alert() across application and set it to new position.
We have many jsp pages in our application, in which we have used Ext.MessageBox.alert(), now the requirement is to reposition all message boxes, without touching their code in jsp..i can include a js file though

Option 1:
i found i am able to reposition a message alert by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1...l-align-with-y 
but then i have to change all jsp pages and add:

```
msgBox=Ext.MessageBox.alert(jsonData.responseMessage);
msgBox.getPositionEl().setTop(50);
```

Option 2: extend the message box : still change all jsp

Option 3: use css : dont know how?

Can anyone please guide me if there is anyother solution or Css solution will be fine:

My code is below

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url : 'submitAddZone.htm',
                        params : {
                                                zoneName : Ext.getCmp('zoneNameId').getValue(),
                                                emailParam : Ext.getCmp('emailId').getValue(),
                                                requestTypeParam : Ext.getCmp('requestTypeId').getValue(),
                                                level : selectedLevel + 1,
                                                parentZoneName : selectedParentZone,
                                                currency : currencyValue,
                                                startDate : Ext.getCmp('startDateId').getValue(),
                                                startTime : Ext.getCmp('startTimeId').getValue()
                                            },
                                            method : 'POST',

                                            success : function(response,request) {
                                                toggleAddZoneElements();

                                                       var jsonData = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                                                       if(jsonData.isSuccess){
                                                       msgBox=   Ext.MessageBox.alert(jsonData.responseMessage);
                                                     msgBox.getPositionEl().setTop(50);

                                                       addZoneWin.close();
                                                       toggleAddZoneButtons();
                                                       tree.getStore().load({url: 'loadCustomerStructure.htm'});
                                                       }else{
                                                       Ext.getCmp('sendRequest').setIcon();
                                                       Ext.getCmp('errorMessage1').setText(Encoder.htmlDecode(jsonData.errorMessage));
                                                       Ext.getCmp('errorMessage1').show();
                                                       }
                                            },
                                            failure : function(
                                                    response) {
                                                toggleAddZoneElements();
                                                msgBox= Ext.MessageBox.alert(notCreatedLabel);
                                                addZoneWin.close();
                                                msgBox.getPositionEl().setTop(50);
                                            }

                                        });
```

Comment: the link to the stackoverflow question in option 1 points to void.

Answer (score 0):

A clean solution would be to create your own MessageBox class which offers a custom alert method, in which you would call Ext.MessageBox.alert() and change the position. But this would require you to change all your jsp files.

Now it gets dirty: You can try to override Ext.MessageBox.alert:

```
Ext.override(Ext.MessageBox,{
    alert: function(message){
         var msgBox = Ext.MessageBox.alert(message);
         msgBox.getPositionEl().setTop(50);
    }
});
```

But this affects ALL calls to Ext.MessageBox.alert(). I would not like to have such a hack in my code.